# Promise: then is not defined (asynchronous call)

Tags: angularjs, promise

I am trying to fill `$scope.data` with the data that I get from:

```
function getUserData(callback) {
    FB.api('/me/friends', function (response) {
        if (callback) return callback(response.data);
        return response.data;
    });
}
```

Because it's an asynchronous call, I am using promise in order to fill it.

This method is found in my controller:

```
Typekit.GetData().then(function (data) {
     $scope.data = data;
});
```

This is my factory:

```
App.factory('TypekitService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
      return {
          GetData: function () {
               return getUserData(callback);
               function callback(data) {
                   var deferred = $q.defer();
                   deferred.resolve(window.userRates);
                   return deferred.promise;
               }
          }
      }
}]);
```

Unfortunately, I get:

`Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You aren't actually returning a promise.

Comment: `GetData` returns the result of calling `getUserData`, but `getUserData` does not return a promise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot call method 'then' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915054/cannot-call-method-then-of-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because `getUserData` doesnt return promise

```
function getUserData(callback) {
    return FB.api('/me/friends', function (response) {
        if (callback) return callback(response.data);
        return response.data;
    });
}
```

or

```
function getUserData(callback) {
    var p = $q.defer()
    FB.api('/me/friends', function (response) {
        if (callback) return callback(response.data);
        p.resolve(response.data)
    });
    return p.promise
}
```

Comment: Who is dislike it?

Comment: @AlonShmiel Probably someone who knows that `FB.api` doesn't return promise so the first example will not work. Or maybe someone who see that the second example is also not ideal (errors are not handled, callback is not cleaned up).

Answer (score 1):

As it is, the promise will be created when the data has actually been returned. Try something along the lines of:

```
GetData: function () {
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     getUserData(function(data) {
         deferred.resolve(data);
     });
     return deferred.promise;
}
```

This way you return the promise (so `GetData(...).then()` is defined) and only *resolve* the promise in the callback.

Comment: I wonder why the downvotes for both answers - they seem correct to me. Does the downvoter care to explain or does she/he prefer hit and run tactics?

Comment: Who is dislike it?

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to your service with `Typekit` but it is exposed by your factory as `TypekitService`.

Comment: I declared it fine: App.controller('ScrollCtrl', ['$scope', 'TypekitService',  '$http', '$q', function ($scope, Typekit, http, $q) { ... }])

Comment: It's not shown in the code you posted, but as long as you have then it's a non-issue. In the future, posting complete code would be helpful.